# Render multiple JSON objects using jsRender

Tags: jsrender

I want to return data that consists of a JSON object with two sub objects. On the client I want to be able to use a jsRender {{for}} construct to loop through only one particular object at a time.

I am able to render everything without using {{for}} but I'd like to use {{for}}.

So why doesn't this work?

```
<script id="progDetailsTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for Programmes}}{{!-- Why won't this work? -->}}
    <tr><td>{{>GroupName}}</td></tr>
    {{/for}}
   </script>
```

this however does work:

```
<script id="progDetailsTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr><td>{{>GroupName}}</td></tr>
   </script>
```

It's possible that other objects could have the same property called 'GroupName' which is why I'd like help with this.

I have created a jsFiddle so you can see the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/SNSXs/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your problem is with the object you pass to render method. You passed `dataResults.Programmes` and tried to access `Programmes` property. What you needed to do is pass `dataResults` and it will work.

I made changes on your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNSXs/2/) example. The only change is in call method:

```
function BuildProgs() {
    $("#progTable").append(
            $("#progDetailsTemplate").render(dataResults)
        );
}
```

Also, on side note on your js code standard. Let your left curly brace `{` be placed in same line as function name. [This is a good read](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) about javascript code conventions

Comment: Oh I see - easy when you know how. Also thanks for the JS code standard article. Added to my list of things to read :-)

Comment: You can alternatively miss out the {{for Programmes}} tag. Also best to use a <tbody> if later you move to JsViews, since browsers add <tbody>s if you don't put one there...
See http://jsfiddle.net/SNSXs/4/